# How can I spawn an Android crouton from the bottom?

Tags: android, crouton

I am using keyboardsurfer's [crouton](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton) library as a replacement for toasts.  I am curious if there is an easy way to spawn the crouton from the `bottom` rather than the `action bar`.  I looked at `Configuration` but didn't notice anything that would help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton/issues/84
which leads to https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton/pull/132
which leads to https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton/issues/169 :(

In short: not available yet but you'd simply need to take the proposed pull request and format it to the new Android Studio source tree structure.

Comment: I guess I could make an invisible `ViewGroup` that is floated to the bottom, and attach the `crouton` to that with `Crouton.makeText(Activity, int, Style, ViewGroup)`?

Answer (score 3):

You can create an empty LinearView in your activity xml file and make it as a footer. Make sure to set it's visibility as gone. Something like below:

```
<LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/croutonview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

  </LinearLayout>
```

Then call the crouton.makeText() with an extra parameter having this linearview's resource id.
Something like this:

> Crouton.makeText(
>                 this,
>                 "crouton message"
>                 de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget.crouton.Style.INFO,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.croutonview))
>                 .show();

Hope it helps!